# How to add strings before the table gets bind in the rich text box control

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms, string

I have a query like this

```
@"SELECT 
                                                   TABLE_NAME
                                                  AS
                                                   TABLES
                                                FROM 
                                                   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS
                                               WHERE 
                                                   CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'PRIMARY KEY'
                                                 AND
                                                   TABLE_NAME <> 'dtProperties'
                                            ORDER BY
                                                   TABLE_NAME";
```

this gives the list of all table names that have primary key in a rich textbox control

Now I want to add something like "Here are the lists of tables that have primary keys...followed by the table names.

Is there anyone who will guide me....

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Union** to add your string.

Answer (score 0):

First declare string and assign what u want like "Here are the lists of tables that have primary keys" and using data reader U read each value and add it to that.After that assign that string to rich text box text.

add it in string  by `string s=s+"\n"+dataReader[0];`